# jquery continuously check if element has specific attribute and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a div when an `a` has a specifc `href` and show it when it doesn't have that specifc `href`

I've tried this:

```
if($('a[href="#intro"]').not(".active")) 
  { $('.navbar-brand').hide();} 
else {$('.navbar-brand').show();}
```

But this is not working as expected, it hides that div when that specific `href` has a class of `active`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `if($('a[href="#intro"]').length)` ??? It could be finally: `$('.navbar-brand').toggle(!$('a[href="#intro"]').length);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var show = $('a[href="#intro"]').hasClass('active');
$('.navbar-brand').toggle(show);
```

Comment: "I want to hide a div when an a has a specifc href" but quite confusing why OP is checking for an active class. And anyway here, should be: `.hasClass('active')`

Comment: @A.Wolff Agreed. I just translated his snippet to a working version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't use well :not see https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
if($('a[href="#intro"]:not(".active")') 
  { $('.navbar-brand').hide();} 
else {$('.navbar-brand').show();}
```